# Sub_block base_address override?

Tags: origen-sdk

Is there a way to assign a different **base_address** to the sub_blocks of a **sub_block**?

I have a case where I have something like this:

```
dut.rb:

    sub_block ipBlock base_address: 0x11000000
```

and so the registers at this level all start with 0x110000000

But *ipBlock* also has its own sub_blocks:

```
ipblock.rb:

    sub_block subIPBlock base_address: 0x0
```

with its own registers that due to an interface difference require a 0 base_address.

Unfortunately, when I add registers to *subIPBlock* they still have the base address of the top-level *ipBlock*:

```
sub_ipblock.rb:

    add_reg :reg0, 0x0, 16, reset: 0xFFFF ...
```

Is there is a way to easily reassign the base address of the sub_block of a sub_block?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use [sub-block domains](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/models/registers/#Per-Domain_Base_Addresses) to achieve what you want.

```
sub_block :subx2, class_name: "SubX", base_address: { ips: 0x2000_0000, ahb: 0x3000_0000 }
dut.subx1.reg1.address(domain: :ips)  # => 0x2000_0200
dut.subx1.reg1.address(domain: :ahb)  # => 0x3000_0200
```

regards

Comment: Cool,thanks. Is there a way to indicate a default domain for a sub_block?   Ideally I'd want the higher-level sub_block to use one domain while the lower-level sub_block to use another -- by default.

Comment: @D.Hadad I don't think so currently.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answer, also note that `reg.offset` will return the block relative address, which it sounds like you want here.

All Origen drivers should override the register's address when an `:address` option is given, so within your model you could implement a read/write register method to add an `:address` option:

```ruby
def write_register(reg, options = {})
  if your_criteria_to_use_local_address
    options[:address] = reg.offset
  end
  dut.write_register(reg, options)  # Handover for original write
end
```

You could also force/override the base address within your model by implementing the following method:

```ruby
def reg_base_address(options = {})
  0
end
```

Finally, note that when using the domains per @rchitect-of-info's answer, you can define two domains when you instantiate a parent sub-block, then when you instantiate a child of that sub-block you can pick which of the available domains it is assigned to.

See this example from the documentation linked to in the other answer:

```ruby
$dut.subx2.suby1.reg1.address          # => 0x2000_0300
$dut.subx2.suby2.reg1.address          # => 0x3000_0300
```